# Adams Spectral Sequence for Triangulated Categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, spectral-sequences, triangulated-categories

We have the Adams SS with 
$$ E_2^{p,q} = Ext^{p,q} _{E^*(E)}([S,E],[S,E]) $$
where $E$ is the Eilenberg-Maclane Spectrum yielding $\mathbb{Z}/p$ coefficients.

I was wondering if there is a SS for arbitrary compactly generated triangulated categories of which this is special case.

More specifically I am curious if we assume our category to have enough projectives (or injectives) can we avoid invoking the smash product? I am new to Stable Homotopy theory and think of smash products as black box. It would be really delightful if I could replace having a smash product by having enough projectives or something similar but algebraic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the notes of Haynes Miller see http://jdc.math.uwo.ca/papers/ideals.pdf

Answer (score 5):

[These course notes](http://math.mit.edu/~hrm/18.917/notes.pdf) by Haynes Miller seem to be doing exactly what you ask. In the general case the smash product is replaced by a [symmetric monoidal structure](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category), which has to interact well with the triangulated structure.

Answer (score 4):

A general treatment of the Adams spectral sequence in the context of triangulated categories based on the work of Brinkmann and Christensen can be found here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.1344.

No monoidal structure is necessary (although, in applications, you might use a monoidal structure to define a homological ideal).